# I want to understand how the value of x changes when recursive function 'fun' is called

Tags: c, variables, scope, lifetime, static-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int n)
{
    static int x = 0;
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    if (n>3)
    {
        x =n;
        return fun(n-2)+ 3;
    }
    return fun(n-1)+ x;
}
int main()
{
   return fun(5);
}
```

How i am thinking is that when in the `main()` function `fun(5)` is called. It satisfies the if condition `if(n>3)`. The value of 'n' which is 5 is assigned to the x by `x =n;`. In the next statement `return fun(n-2)+3;` will be `fun(3)+3;`. so where am i getting confused is that when `fun(3)` is executed will the value of be '5' or '0' after the statement `static int x = 0;`. I assumed it stays '5' in the block of `if` condition. How static variables act in these kind of recursive functions.

Comment: `x = n; printf("x changed to %d.\n", n);`

Comment: "_How static variables act in these kind of recursive functions._" Same as function-static variables act everywhere: one value is shared between every call of the function. To see the specifics, step through it in your debugger.

Comment: Right after `static int x = 0;`, use `printf(" n = %d, x = %d\n", n, x);` so that it'll be obvious what the value of `x` for each call.

Comment: Once initiated static variables remain in memory while the program is running, it's kind of like their cope starts on initiation and ends when the program stops. Recommended read: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/

Also as @underscore_d says, use your debugger and step through the program. It's a good way to develop understanding.

Comment: i added `printf(" n = %d, x = %d\n", n, x); ` right after `static int x = 0;` `n = 5, x = 0,n = 3, x = 5, n = 2, x = 5, n = 1, x = 5, n = 0, x = 5`. what did declaration static int x = 0; did when fun(3) was called.

Comment: `static int x = 0;` is not a statement. It is a declaration. The `= 0` part says what initial value is given to `x` when `x` is created, which is when the program starts.

Comment: Debug fail.....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function

```
int fun(int n)
{
    static int x = 0;
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    if (n > 3) {
        x = n;
        return fun(n - 2) + 3;
    }
    return fun(n - 1) + x;
}
```

works exactly like

```
static int x = 0;

int fun(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    if (n > 3) {
        x = n;
        return fun(n - 2) + 3;
    }
    return fun(n - 1) + x;
}
```

except that in the former case, *x* can only be accessed inside *fun*.